# On the commutativity of the tensor product

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, manifolds, tensor-products

I am reading Tu's book "An introduction to Manifolds". Specifically, I am reading about the the exterior algebra of multicovectors (subchapter 1.3) and I am following a proof stating that the wedge product is anticommutative (i.e. proposition 3.21). So, I will state the steps followed by the book and then I will explain my concerns.

If $f\in A_k(V)$ and $g\in A_l(V)$, then we define $\tau\in S_{k+l}$ to be the permutation
$$\tau=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & ... & l & l+1 & ... & l+k\\
k+1 & ... & k+l & 1 & ... & k
\end{bmatrix}$$

And we will try to prove that $A(f\otimes g)(v_1,...,v_{k+l})=\text{sgn}(\tau)A(g\otimes f)(v_1,...,v_{k+l})$ hence showing that the wedge product is commutative as well. We start with the definition of the alternating operator
$$A(f\otimes g)(v_1,...,v_{k+l})=\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}
\text{sgn}(\sigma)f(v_{\sigma(1)},...v_{\sigma(l)})g(v_{\sigma(k+1)},...v_{\sigma(k+l)})
\\=
\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}
\text{sgn}(\sigma)
f(v_{\sigma\tau(l+1)},...v_{\sigma\tau(l+k)})g(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},...v_{\sigma\tau(l)})
\\=\text{sgn}(\tau)
\sum_{\sigma\in S_{k+l}}
\text{sgn}(\sigma\tau)
g(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},...v_{\sigma\tau(l)})f(v_{\sigma\tau(l+1)},...v_{\sigma\tau(l+k)})
\\=
\text{sgn}(\tau)A(g\otimes f)(v_1,...,v_{k+l})$$
where in the second step the definition of $\tau$ was used and then from the second to third step lies my question: **why is the author allowed to swap the order of the functions $f$ and $g$? I take it that the wedge product is not commutative, otherwise it would be stated somewhere in the book, right? So, is he allowed to change the order of the two functions because they are inside the sum? Some help would be appreciated**

The remaining proof is okay, since the author simply identifies the result with the alternating operator, acting on the tensor product of $g$ and $f$, according to the definition...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $f(v_{\sigma\tau(l+1)},...,v_{\sigma\tau(l+k)})$ and $g(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},...,v_{\sigma\tau(l)})$ are real numbers.

Comment: Hi @azif00 and thanks for the comment. Are we certain that it has nothing to do with introducing the permutation $\tau$ in the equation? Because the author changes the order of $f$ and $g$ and at the same time he introduces $\tau$, so I thought that they are related, since those steps happened simultaneously...

Comment: That’s right, that step has nothing to do with $\tau$. From the second to the third step we use two things: (1) $f(v_{\sigma\tau(l+1)},...,v_{\sigma\tau(l+k)})$ and $g(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},...,v_{\sigma\tau(l)})$ commutes because they are real numbers; and (2) $\text{sgn}(\tau) \text{sgn}(\sigma\tau) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)$ since $\text{sgn}(\sigma\tau) = \text{sgn}(\sigma) \text{sgn}(\tau)$ and $\text{sgn}(\tau)^2 = 1$.

Comment: okay, thank you so much!!! However, the tensor product is not always commutative right?

Comment: No, the tensor product itself is never commutative. The only thing a tensor product does is moving scalars: $ v\otimes(4w) = 4(v\otimes w) = (4v)\otimes w$. And bilinearity: $(v\otimes w)+(v\otimes x)=v\otimes(w+x)$ and $v\otimes w+x\otimes w=(v+x)\otimes w$ but _nothing else_.

Comment: okay, thank you

Comment: Tensor product is never commutative and wedge product is, as you're presumably proving, skew-commutative.